# python flask broadcast render template to all users

Tags: flask

Let's say I have a looby with one chat room. Next two people on two different pcs log into the webpage.
PC1 joins the chat room. In this case the lobby of PC2 should automatically show that one guy is now logged into that chat room.

However this currently only happens if PC2 reloads the page....

**Thus what I want to ask do I need sockets to achieve broadcasting or is there also a render_template broadcast to all connected users available in flask?**

Some code:

Problem calling this does not render / update for all logged in users with have currently the rooms_view open...

```
@gaming.route("/rooms", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def rooms_view():
    form = RoomsListFrom()

    return render_template('g_rooms.html', active_btn="Rooms", lang_dict =lang_dict[current_user.language], form=form, room_info=sess_storage)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP protocol depends on request-response life cycle
so you can't respond with another template without a request from a user
you need to use something like socketIO or WebSocket
to trigger the user to make a request to ask for another template